# Mutation observer not able to listen attribute changes via chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, mutation-observers

There is a limitation in salesforce, that is why we are going for chrome extension to listen to data-tabid attribute changes in the dom.

I have created a chrome extension like this:

background.js

```
MutationObserver = window.MutationObserver || window.WebKitMutationObserver;
var observer = new MutationObserver(function (mutations, observer) {

    mutations.forEach(function (mutation) {
        let attributeName1 = mutation.attributeName;
        console.log("Attribute name " + mutation.attributeName +
            " changed to " + mutation.target[attributeName1] +
            " (was " + mutation.oldValue + ")");
    });
});

observer.observe(document, {
    childList: true,
    attributes: true,
    subtree : true,
    attributeOldValue: true,
    attributeFilter: ['data-tabid']
});
```

Manifest.json

```
{
"manifest_version": 2,
"name": "Dom Browser Plugin",
"version": "1.0.0",
"description": "Project Requirement.",
"permissions": [
  "https://*/*",
  "http://*/*",
  "tabs"
],
"background": {
  "scripts": [
    "background.js"
  ],
  "persistent": true
}
}
```

For now in permissions I have given all, I will change this in future, but the observer is not able to catch the data-tabid changes which changes on refresh of the browser. I need to capture the new value and the old value of the data-tabid attribute which is embedded in the dom.

[image]

Full dom screen shot

[image]

Comment: MutationObserver can't detect changes inside iframes because those are like different pages with their own DOM and `document`. If the iframe is same-origin you need to observe its iframe.contentDocument when the iframe is loaded. If it's cross-origin you need to declare your content script to run in that iframe using the corresponding "matches" field and "all_frames":true in manifest.json.

Comment: Thanks for your time, but these are not iframe.

Comment: Really? Your code says ”Listen to the DOM changes to detect when the CTI Iframe is loaded”.

Comment: Thats from some old code which was listening to iframe, for I frames we have `node.addEventListener` when the node is found.

Comment: Judging by the documentation for Salesforce it's using ShadowDOM which should be observed individually on the enclosing shadowRoot.

Comment: I dont think its shadowDOM, its a simple `<ul>` and '<li>' tags:

Please see the updated inspect element screen shot

Comment: Updated is a full dom screen shot

Comment: It could be a timing issue if your content script runs after the change actually occurs. By default content scripts run after DOMContentLoaded.

Comment: I'm sure this is probably not the case, but I had a huge struggle with this because I had the chrome tab open when I enabled the content script-based extension for the first time (despite reloading the page and the extension many times). It seems that it does not allow mutationobserver to work. I made a new tab, and bam. MutationObserver works now.

Answer (score 1):

This happens bacause the background script doesn't receive the window object of the current tab window. MutationObserver object inside background script will refer to background page only. If you doesn't declared the background page in your manifest.json, it will be auto generated with a script tag pointing to the background script. So, MutationObserver will watch changes only at background page. You need a content script to watch changes at the current tab.